# Can SQLCMD be used to set TCP ports?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Is it possible to assign a TCP port using only `SQLCMD`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible via SQLCMD. However, I did just write an answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754129/determine-the-port-that-sql-is-using-or-set-it-if-needed-via-program/25756252#25756252) that does it with powershell.